# Building bitcoind from modified "selfish" code - possible? how?

Tags: bitcoind, regtest, selfish-mining

For a long time I've been trying to find out ways for running a "[selfish mine](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0243)" algorithm on bitcoind's regtest mode.

**Now I'm wondering if my plan is feasible, at all!?** 
So I'll just outline my planned procedure with the hope that I will get useful hints and won't get discouraged since I believe I can achieve my goal with the help of developers and investment of some extra time:

I'm intending to change Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 source code - or a more "suitable" version - in a way that after building bitcoind, in regtest the bitcoind server that is started acts as a selfish miner.
This selfish miner shall connect to other bitcoind nodes that are instances of bitcoind, built out of non-modified code.

My idea is to change a part of the code that communicates (e.g. inv message-part!?) with other nodes: as a selfish miner, newly found blocks should only be shared with other nodes dependent on the selfish mine algorithm so I thought of implementing control structures (if, while, etc.) that work with a comparison of inv message's amount of inventory entries or a similar comparison - e.g. selfish node has found a block and appends it to its inventory and doesn't publish this block if size(selfish.inventory) > size(honest.inventory).

Now a challenge for me is to find out **which part of the source code to modify?** Since it consists of multiple modules that define resembling functions, parameters etc.

I'm ready to read up big amount of code, but the problem is I don't know what part is relevant for my problem.

**What do you think? Is my intention realistic? What are good approaches to a solution?**

Comment: I think you'll find a lot more help forthcoming (and your project will be easier for *you*) if you can delineate your intentions more clearly. What I'm reading is very vague. Start by defining "selfish miner" and it may be people can opine on that

Comment: thanks, I'll edit the post in a while for a clearifying things.